# Showing MessageBox on MouseDown eats up MouseUp event

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I am working on a WPF application where i handled a mouse down event which eventually shows up 
MessageBox.. But after MessageBox appears on mouseDown, it eats up corresponding MouseUp event of a control.

Scenario can be easily reproduced by simply handling MouseDown and MouseUP event in WPF window 
as:-

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.show("Hello, Mouse down");
}

private void Window_MouseUP(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.show("Hello, Mouse Up");
}
```

MouseUp message is never shown, once messagebox appears on MouseDown event.

Comment: Well, the message box is blocking; what happens if you remove the mouse down handler? What is original the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

What about initializing a new instance of `System.Threading.Thread` to call the `MessageBox` so that the main user interface thread would not be interrupted by the prompt?

**Example**

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Thread mythread = new Thread(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello, Mouse Down")); //Initialize a new Thread to show our MessageBox within 
    mythread.Start(); //Start the thread
}

private void Window_MouseUP(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Thread mythread = new Thread(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello, Mouse Up")); //Initialize a new Thread to show our MessageBox within 
    mythread.Start(); //Start the thread
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Calling a MessageBox in a different thread to avoid interrupting the main user interface thread]

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: I cannot show the message on another thread as it creates non-modal message box. If I try to post the message box on dispatcher and show the message then the problem still persist and the issue is not just with mouse up event its with any windows message in the queue those messages are eaten up by message box.

Comment: @Karan [A modal window is a child window that requires users to interact with it before they can return to operating the parent application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). How do you want the `MessageBox` to be modal without interfering with the events? I currently have no ideas to do such a thing. Sorry about that :(

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter on your original post said, it seems that what's happening here is that the user's mouse wanders out of focus to click in the message box, or even just to display it, so the mouse moves "up" anyway - the event is never called.
If you're just wanting to display messageboxes, then simply using:

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.show("Hello, Mouse down");
   MessageBox.show("Hello, your mouse must be up because you've shifted focus!");
}
```

should do the job. If this behaviour repeats for something like changing a window title, or anything that doesn't require user input, then this could be a problem, but I am 100% sure that this is just an issue with regards to the MessageBox. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

@picrofo solution is also good and easy but i did by this way

```
  DialogResult result;
 private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "would you like to see mouse up event?";
        string caption = "event trick";
        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;

        result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            button1_MouseUp(sender, e);

        }

    }
```